# use "self" in the shader node driver

Tags: materials, drivers

I want to make a shader with image sequence, which is gonna be controlled by null(empty). So closer the null to an object, the more image offset is gonna be. Image sequence offset is linked to value node using driver, so I can slide image sequence progress. I want to link it to the distance between null and the object itself.

So what I need to get here is distance between object and null. But I don't know how to say to driver to refer to objects' position. Self isn't working here, because, I think, self references to material, not the object. What I wanted to ask, is there a way to say to material driver to refer object that material was applied? I want it to do this automatically, because I will have 50-100 of these objects

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible because I think the driver is only evaluated once for each material, then all the objects use the same evaluated material. If you can find a way to do with something you can control with a socket instead of an image sequence it would be easier.

Comment: @scurest oh, thats really unfortunate :(

Well, I just started to make simpler version, but I stuck on this moment.
I want to make so if object is in the gradient area, it will turn FULLY to different texture. But I doesn't work as I intended - it becomes different texture only on the edge of gradient, it doesn't turn whole object to different texture. You know what might be solution here?

Can't find a way to insert screenshots, but I hope it is not necessary to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the Object Viewport Color using the "Object Info" node, in the shader editor, allowing you to change the properties in a material per object it's on. And if you split that into RGB, you can make 3 unique values to change in a material by putting a driver on the R, G and B of the viewport color.